# Disable shipping method based on chosen payment method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I need to disable specific shipping method if user selected payment "Cash on Delivery". The problem is that the following code works only if I reset
WooCommerce transients each time and refresh. It doesn't work on user selection back and forth.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'alter_shipping_methods', 100 );
function alter_shipping_methods( $rates ) {

    $chosen_gateway = WC()->session->chosen_payment_method;

    // If payment is Cash on delivery remove specific shipping 
    if($chosen_gateway == 'cod') {

        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
           if ( $rate->label === 'Hrvatska pošta' ) {
              unset( $rates[ $rate_id ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

I do have this code which should trigger and I see the output in console when I click around options.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function() {
    console.log('Payment method changed');
    jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
});
```

I have tried with this, it doesn't work:

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review($array, $int) {
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
    return;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 10, 2);
```

And I have also tried custom AJAX call which calls a PHP function and inside this filter, no result:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'alter_shipping_methods', 100 );
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated on March 2019**

> For COD payment gateways, you can just add **in its settings** the "Flat rate" shipping methods that you want to enable for it, like:
>
> [image]

For Cod and other methods or for others payment gateways, here is the complete working way to disable a specific shipping method(s) for specific payment gateway(s).

You will have to set in the first function the shipping method Id that you wish to hide.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates','show_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function show_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE Define your targeted shipping method ID
    $payment_method        = 'cod';

    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method ){
        unset($rates['flat_rate:12']);
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'payment_methods_trigger_update_checkout' );
function payment_methods_trigger_update_checkout(){
    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change blur', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                }, 250 );
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods' );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    // HERE Define your targeted shipping method ID
    $payment_method = 'cod';
    $bool           = true;

    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') === $payment_method )
        $bool = false;

    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

To be able **to get the correct shipping method ID** you can use your browser inspector, this way:

[image]

> You may need to empty cart before testing this code.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, can you update to hide the other PAYMENT methods too please?

Comment: @FilipeOS How that *(I don't catch)*? … This answer is working as it is.

Comment: according your answer, if you choose COD shipping method the other payment methods still show and you can ask to COD+pay for example with paypal.. This is why I want to hide the payment methods if COD shipping is selected.

Comment: @FilipeOS Sorry the code was not working anymore… So I have change it and I have removed unneeded Ajax. Try it and give me some feed back.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I installed on the last version of WP and WC but, after the first execution, the update enter in a loop and never stops... is there an issue?

Comment: @user1142705 Just tested that on last WP and WC versions on last version of Storefront theme, and there is no issue .

Comment: Hi, your code works fine, I just got a question... What about if you wanna assign next to cod paypal too? So that 2 payment methods would be available for specific shipping.