# Disable shipping methods based on chosen payment method - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout

I have an issue with Woocommerce. I would like to hide certain shipping methods based on the choice of payment method.

I want all 3 payment methods ("bacs", "cod" and "przelewy24") to be always visible.
Based on the choice of the payment method, there should be only 2 shipping methods shown:

If payment method = "bacs" or "przelewy24", then I want only those 2 shipping methods to be shown:
`flexible_shipping_single:25 flexible_shipping_single:26`

If payment method = "cod", then I want only those 2 shipping methods to be shown:
`flexible_shipping_single:23 flexible_shipping_single:24`

I know that I can easily hide payment methods based on the shipping method, but I need it to be the other way around.

Do you guys know how can it be solved? :)

I was trying to figure it out using this thread: [Disable shipping method based on chosen payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412379/disable-shipping-method-based-on-chosen-payment-method-in-woocommerce)

But I failed :(

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates','show_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function show_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE Define your targeted shipping method ID
   
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    if( $payment_method == 'cod' ){ //if cod, hide unnecessary shipping methods
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:25']);
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:26']);
    }
    elseif ( $payment_method == 'przelewy24' ) //if przelewy24, hide unnecessary shipping methods
    {
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:23']);
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:24']);
    }
    elseif ( $payment_method == 'bacs' ) //if bacs, hide unnecessary shipping methods
    {
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:23']);
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:24']);
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'payment_methods_trigger_update_checkout' );
function payment_methods_trigger_update_checkout(){
    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change blur', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                }, 250 );
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

// TO BE COMPLETLY HONEST, I DON'T REALLY KNOW WHAT I WAS SUPPOSED TO DO BELOW

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods' );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    // HERE Define your targeted shipping method ID
    $bool           = true;

    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') === 'cod' )
        $bool = false;

if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') === 'przelewy24' )
        $bool = false;

if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') === 'bacs' )
        $bool = false;



    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

Comment: You're using the `$chosen_payment_method` variable to store the value but for check `$payment_method` is being used which is nowhere defined.